# Do Map.keys and Map.values give parallel sequences of elements in the same order?

Tags: scala

Assume we have a standard `scala.collection.immutable.Map`. Is the following assertion true? Does it hold for all types of maps?

I have inspected the source code of `MapLike`. It seems `.keys` and `.values` use the same iterator, but I am not sure of the exact behavior of such iterator.

```
val a = Map(....)
val keys = a.keys.toSeq
val values = a.values.toSeq
val seq = a.toSeq
assert(seq == keys.zip(values))
```

Comment: The order is guaranteed by all “sane” implementations if the collection is not modified between the two calls.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for the comment, but why? Also the map is immutable therefore it cannot be modified

Comment: Because of implementation details, and the soft expectations that leak out - there is nothing “random” to iteration. Naturally, one could create a forward-keys / backward-values if feeling devious.. then the question becomes one of any contractual guarantees on the specific implementation. The only counter would thus be a contractual guarantee on the interface itself (making implementations conforming or otherwise).

Comment: Up to 4 element in Map the order is maintained after that it doesn’t. As the Map is not a ordered DS you can not rely on the methods .keys and .values because it will give you values and keys for that instance of the Map and it’s not always same. If you want to maintain the order of Map use ListMap like DS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be true for the current implementation of these collections but you cannot assume that it will be true in the general case. If you want the order of the keys to be guaranteed, use `ListMap`.

If you need the keys and values as separate lists while guaranteeing that the elements in each list correspond, do this:

```
val (keys, values) = a.unzip
```